# Is there a shortcut to expand all folders in Finder's list view?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, folders

I have my Finder window set up to display in "list" view so that it shows all folders with triangles on the left to click to expand. I have a number of levels of nested folders. Is there any way (keyboard shortcut, menu item, etc.) to expand all, so I don't have to click through each level to see the files contained?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Select the folder you want (or <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all) and then press:

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd>

And the left arrow undoes what the right arrow did, should you want to close things back up again. Using option instead of command works on all folders enclosed in the selected folder. Both option and command modify a mouse selection on the folder toggle icon “triangle” or “arrow” to execute these shortcuts using the GUI.

Comment: [option] + [right arrow] is enough

Comment: [option] + [right arrow] expands all subdirectories as well, whereas [command]+[right arrow] expands only the selected directories

Comment: option click recursively expands all subfolders whereas option right arrow expands all the selected folders but not the subfolders

Answer (score 16):

I find mouse/trackpad-clicking the triangle while holding the Alt/Option or Command key works too.

Comment: This is a much better solution if you wanna expand the whole tree, including sub-trees!

Comment: It does not work in all use cases. For example in "iCloud Drive", where you have no 'root' to click on. In these cases the accepted answer still works. But I agree, I use ⌥+click more often :) But it is still useful to have the accepted answer in your 'knowledge box' as well.

Answer (score 8):

To expand one single level folder

<kbd>Command</kbd>  <kbd>Right arrow</kbd>

To expand all levels of subfolders under the selected folder.

<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>Right arrow</kbd>

OR

<kbd>Option</kbd> and click the triangle in folder view in Finder